# Replace character with linebreak

Tags: php

Im trying to make a decompiler,
I finaly managed to decompile the code to a string,
but I want to add a linebreak after the character ";"
so I tried:

```
str_replace(";", ";\n", $data);
file_put_contents($name.'.php', $data);
```

But it doesn't seem to create a linebreak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this :

```
 $data = str_replace(";", ";\r\n", $data);
```

The str_replace functions returns a string, it does not modify the string passed in parameters.

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Great :) Please note my answer as accepted by clicking on the gray "check" icon below the vote count. Thanks

Comment: I will but I need to wait 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

for new line break use following syntax:

```
 $data = str_replace(";", ";\r\n", $data);
```

for Apache server, we have to always use \r before \n for line break.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the output of str_replace to anything. Also, if you're looking at your file in Windows, you should also add a carriage return `"\r"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
$data = str_replace(";", ";\r\n", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try

```
str_replace(";", ";\n\r", $data);
file_put_contents($name.'.php', $data);
```

And Try to open in notepad++ or sublime Text

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows, you might want to try `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, or maybe look into the [PHP constant `PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which contains

> The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

`"\r\n"` would still be the best solution for cross system compatibility though. More info about that can be found [in this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n)

Comment: This is not the main problem here. The main issue is that the return of str_replace is not assigned to anything.

Comment: May be not the main problem, but still relevant, and even important, to his question.